# Is an additional middleware needed in Laravel to handle CORS?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

In **Laravel** (10 btw) there is a **CORS config file** available out of the box (/config/cors.php). However, Laravel doesn´t expose CORS headers by default when using the API routes (e.g. no "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is present in the server response).

Now I´ve tried to find a solution on the web but all "best practices" I´ve found are **creating an own CORS middleware** to attach CORS headers to the http response (and they mostly ignore the cors config file for any reason).

So I´m wondering if there is another - "framework made" - way of adding CORS headers to API responses **without adding an own "hacky" middleware**? I think there should be cause there is a cors config file out of the box...!?

Comment: What does [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#cors) mention on the topic?

Comment: laravel only adds the headers on a preflight request

Comment: The default `cors.php` [definitely does apply to the API routes](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/a546b52b3bbbfd06361d9feada3932f95eb5ef82/config/cors.php#L18) with its `'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],` setting. Your browser will send a preflight `OPTIONS` request to get the header; non-browser requests (like in Postman) don't care about CORS at all.

Comment: Ok - so what´s the best practice? Should I add an additional OPTIONS request to the client (angular) or "manually" add the CORS headers to all responses in Laravel?

Comment: @Mike You should leave it alone; your browser will already send the `OPTIONS` request automatically where appropriate. What specific problem are you having? Is your Angular app throwing a CORS error? What does it say?

Comment: @Ceejayoz: I´ve a an Angular SPA on a seperate subdomain which consumes the REST API exposed by my Laravel application (which therefore causes the CORS block as expected). However the Angular application doesn´t "automatically" send an OPTIONS request before following requests.

Comment: @Mike How are you making these requests, and are they actually failing? Your Angular app doesn't automatically do this; your *browser* does, where it deems appropriate. It's built-in. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests

Comment: @ceejayoz That´s exactly the issue - the angular http client doesn´t send the OPTIONS request (automatically) before the GET request. So the question is: Add the CORS response headers "manually" via middleware to Laravel or add an additional OPTIONS requests on the client side? Both should be possible although I haven´t found much on that topic for Angular so far...

Answer (score 0):

- If your client is in the same domain as the server, you don't have to worry about CORS.
- Headers should only be added on the server side in response to a request.
- There are great packages for laravel that will do this for you, as an example [laravel-cors package](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors)